# Convert int to float/double and then convert back, always same?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

In c++, I have an integer number, I convert it to float/double, and then I convert it back to integer. Are the two integers assured to be exactly the same always? Assume the range of floating numbers cover the range of the integer numbers.

Comment: Only if the mantissa of the float/double has as many bits as the integer.

Comment: it depends on how you convert it back. int(float_version + 0.5) == original_int. int(float_version)maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily, if you're working with a 32 bit integer and a 32 bit float (which is fairly typical) you have the potential for some rounding error between the conversion from the integer to the float (As typically the float will only have 24 bits to store the actual number (the mantissa)).

However, as the exact sizes of the basic types in C are not strictly defined, it is possible for this conversion to work (For example if floats were stored as 64 bits and integers of 32 bits).

Basically, figure of the size of your integer on the systems you are interested in and ensure you use floating-point value with a large enough Mantissa.

Answer (score 4):

As a concrete counterexample, to show it isn't always the case with float

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main(){
    int x = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    float f = x;
    int xf = f;
    double d = x;
    int xd = d;

    std::cout <<  x << '\n' 
              <<  f << '\n' 
              << xf << '\n'
              <<  d << '\n'
              << xd << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

on my system outputs

```
2147483647
2.14748e+09
-2147483648
2.14748e+09
2147483647
```

Comment: None of those casts is needed. Nor is `std::endl`; `'\n'` ends a line without the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.